# Error while installing Cypress: Cypress cannot run because this binary file does not have executable permissions here:

Tags: cypress, yarnpkg

Getting an error while installing [Cypress.io](https://docs.cypress.io/). I followed the steps in the documentation and still getting the following error:

```
Cypress cannot run because this binary file does not have executable permissions here:

/Library/Caches/Cypress/6.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress

Reasons this may happen:

- node was installed as 'root' or with 'sudo'
- the cypress npm package as 'root' or with 'sudo'

Please check that you have the appropriate user permissions.

You can also try clearing the cache with 'cypress cache clear' and reinstalling.
```

The folder structure is `app/e2e/`, and basically right now only contains the `yarn.lock` & `package.json`.

Commands I ran were:

```
yarn init
yarn add cypress
yarn run cypress open
```

then tried:

```
sudo yarn add cypress
yarn run cypress open
```

still didn't work, so then I tried:

```
cypress cache clear
```

which still didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

After following a few threads here on SO and some on the cypress repo, here's what helped me, and I hope it helps someone else.

In my case, I deleted the existing e2e folder(probably not needed) and then made a new e2e folder inside my app and then ran the following:

```
yarn init
yarn add cypress
yarn run cypress install // this was the key
yarn run cypress open
```

Now I get all the base files that come with a fresh install of cypress.